# Extjs Store Getting Data from Post

Tags: extjs, extjs5

Good Morning,

I have a search endpoint that I that works when I call it like this:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '/Search/False',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    params: 'Attribute:ClosedDT;Value:2014-12-16',
    success: function(conn, response, options, eOpts) {
        alert(conn.responseText);
    },
    failure: function(conn, response, options, eOpts) {
        alert(conn.responseText);
    }
});
```

I want to use a proxy to load it into a store directly. After much googling I have tried this and i get back a **POST /Search/False?_dc=1418738135737 net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE**

See current code below:

```
var proxyDefinition = {
    type : 'rest',
    api : {
        read : '/Search/False'
    },
    actionMethods : {
        read    : 'POST'
    },
    reader : {
        type : 'json'
    },
    paramsAsJson:true       
};

returnValue = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Mdl1',
    proxy: proxyDefinition
});
returnValue.load({params: 'Attribute:ClosedDT;Value:2014-12-16'});
```

Comment: I think there is a bug related to 'paramAsJson', please refer to http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?284374-AjaxProxy-with-paramsAsJson for more info.

Comment: to start debugging use a callback when loading http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-load (I would also consider explicitly setting the root property in the reader object) http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader

Comment: Can you use the Chrome developer tools to see what's actually being sent through? The ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE is surely due to the server response so can we see the request that triggers that response.

Answer (score 0):

The params config needs to be an object, not a string. Extjs will encode it for you because of paramsAsJson: true.

You should use:

```
    params: {
Attribute: 'CloseDT',
Value: '204-12-16'
}
```